# What to use instead of DATEPART to extract current week?

Tags: date, frameworks, cognos

In Cognos Framework, what should I use to retrieve week from a date instead of DATEPART? I do not want to follow ISO. I want 1/02/2016 to be Week 6.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to follow a business calendar, you need to setup a calendar table.  One record per date, each record has week number in Calendar year, and week number in fiscal year, and week number in month (calendar and fiscal).  You can setup multiple calendars this way (for example if your marketing week is seperate from your accounting week, etc).  Also a great place to setup relative date fields (which simplify alot of cognos reporting).

Comment: I have a calendar table but maintained by following ISO standard. What else can I do?

Comment: Custom calendar table.  You have got to map out your definition of the calendar.  Keep it in a different database if you don't have access to change the one you are pulling your primary query from.

Comment: My team members do not agree in this way. They want to do it in framework instead of database. my report goes wrong when I use this code:

'WK ' + right('0' + convert(varchar(2), datepart ({wk}, ( cast([Database View].[GSDSX_ORDERS].[AUDAT],timestamp)))),2)

Comment: Creating a table is fun and easy.  You will feel great every time you use it and it saves you hours of goofing around with date syntax like in your statement above.